# Need help on a power shell script to filter the CSV on Columns and display the filtered data in new sheet

Tags: powershell

I am new to power shell but learning it fast. So far i have made a script which is fetching the data from URL and creating a csv on the desktop and then i remove the first row from the CSV and saving it to desktop as csv2. I want to filter the column and copy the filtered data in new sheet. I may have to declare the array values to be looked for filtering and i need help on that. So far i have made the below script:-

\This script is made to download the asset analysis servers list with their corresponding site address and country and will save the output to CSV on C:\Users\vtarwani\Desktop.

```
Invoke-WebRequest -Uri "Link to URL" -OutFile "C:\Users\tarwaniv\Desktop\file1.csv"
    $import = get-content "C:\Users\tarwaniv\Desktop\file1.csv"
    $import | select-Object -Skip 1 | Set-Content "C:\Users\tarwaniv\Desktop\file2.csv"
    Import-csv -Path "C:\Users\tarwaniv\Desktop\file2.csv" -Header "#Active Servers", "Street Address" , "City", "Country" | Where-Object {$_.Country -eq "UNITED STATES"}
```

Comment: So what's the actual question? You may share a few sanitized lines of your input CSV and the expected output.

Comment: I have a 13th column with header as 'Country", It has 15 unique values, I want to filter each values and its corresponding Name and Address column and print that in 15 new sheets.

Comment: # Active Servers Scope Scope Changed Discovered Dt Asset Status Serial Number Status1 Status2 HB Age Location Street Address City Country
####### IN_SCOPE 6/26/2020 6/26/2020 NEW UNDEF INSTALL   UNDEF UNDEF UNDEF UNDEF
######## IN_SCOPE 6/26/2020 6/26/2020 NEW UNDEF UNSUPPORTED_OS   UNDEF UNDEF UNDEF UNDEF
####### IN_SCOPE 6/26/2020 6/26/2020 NEW UNDEF UNSUPPORTED_OS   UNDEF UNDEF UNDEF UNDEF                              I want to filter the csv with column 13 with 15 unique values and print their corresponding server names, Street address, City and country in different 15 sheets.

Comment: # Active Servers Street Address City Country
Server Name Server Site Address VEURNE BELGIUM
Server Name Server Site Address VEURNE BELGIUM     Expected output

Comment: If you look at your comments, you will probably also notice that this has become really unreadable. Please use the [edit](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/62636325/edit) link underneath your question and paste the extra info in there as [formatted](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/22186/how-do-i-format-my-code-blocks/22189#22189) text.

Comment: I used the beloe code and it did not work either   {Invoke-WebRequest -Uri "URL Address" -OutFile "C:\Users\tarwaniv\Desktop\file1.csv"
import-csv "C:\Users\tarwaniv\Desktop\file1.csv" | Select-Object -Skip 1 | Set-Content "C:\Users\tarwaniv\Desktop\file2.csv"
import-csv "C:\Users\tarwaniv\Desktop\file2.csv" | ConvertFrom-Csv -Header "#Active Servers", "Street Address" , "City", "Country" | Where-Object {$_.Country -in @("ARGENTINA","AUSTRALIA","BELARUS","BELGIUM")} | Export-Csv "C:\Users\tarwaniv\Desktop\file4.csv"}

Comment: Please, do not add more and more comments. Edit your original question and add the requested information there. Sample data should be formatted as code as well please.

Answer (score 0):

I agree with @Theo and @Olaf. This is difficult to follow.  Hopefully you'll be able to build off an example like this:

```
$WebFile = "C:\Users\tarwaniv\Desktop\file1.csv"
$Out_Dir = "C:\Users\tarwaniv\Desktop\"

$Headers = "#Active Servers", "Street Address" , "City", "Country"

Invoke-WebRequest -Uri "Link to URL" -OutFile $WebFile

Import-csv -Path $WebFile -Header  | 
Select-Object -Skip 1 |
Group-Object -Property Country |
ForEach-Object{
    $OutFile = $Out_Dir + $_.Name
    $_.Group | Export-Csv -Path $OutFile -NoTypeInformation
}
```

Note: using `-Skip` parameter on Select object should skip the first record coming from `Import-Csv`.

Use `Group-Object` to group on the Country.  That will output its own objects, but the name property is what you grouped on, in this case Country, and the Group property has the original objects in it.  So we can use these 2 properties to name an output file then export the objects to the new Csv file.

If you want to only output a subset of the columns coming from the initial file. add the `-Property` parameter to the `Select-Object` command like:

```
Select-Object -Skip 1 -Property <PropertiesToSelect>
```

Note: You can declare an array of properties similar to `$Headers` above.

If you want top filter on additional columns, and assuming they were included in the `Select-Object` command just build on the `Where-Object` clause.

Please bear in mind I couldn't really test this, so consider it a starting point.  That said let me know how it turns out.  Thanks.

Comment: It missed the header parameter and when i added the parameters like ********* {Import-csv -Path $WebFile -Header "#Active Servers", "Street Address" , "City", "Country"  | 
Select-Object -Skip 1 |
Group-Object -Property Country |
ForEach-Object{
    $OutFile = $Out_Dir + $_.Name
    $_.Group | Export-Csv -Path $OutFile -NoTypeInformation
}}********* it created multiple files on my desktop

Comment: I could write the code in using the code quotes in the first time i asked the question, but while writing the comments, I dont see thst option to write the code in a seperate format.

Comment: As others have mentioned you need to edit your original question to include the sample data.  If you format it as code it will be readable.  Thanks.